# Linq selecting on string value "not equals" ignores DB nulls

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Here's some oddness. A data table, accessed through Entity Framework, has a field with is a nullable string/varchar.

When you attempt to select things using Linq to get items not equal to a given value, i.e.

```
var thingsToRun = rep.Things.Where(t => t.Status != "Running");
```

What you get back is a list of all the Things that have a Status other than "Running" *except* those that have a null status.

In other words if you had three things with a Status of "Running", "NotRunning" and NULL, the above query would only return one item, with a status of "NotRunning".

I presume this is something to do with a mismatch between C# null and DB null. But it seems odd. Is there an easy way round it?

EDIT: Thanks for answers. Still curious about *why* this happens?

Comment: Do you want to omit nulls or do you want to get them? In general this has nothing to do with C# or LINQ but with your database. Normally databases never return null records if you don't search for them explicitly: `WHERE Status IS NULL` or `Status IS NOT NULL`. So a null value is neither `=` nor `!=`, it is simply not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test explicitly for `null`:

```
var thingsToRun
    = rep.Things.Where(t => t.Status == null || t.Status != "Running");
```

As for *why*, Tim provided a good answer in his comments. I'll put something here for the sake of a more complete answer. The value `null` in database land is typically not equal to anything and not "not equal" to anything. It's incomparable  to any value, one way or the other.

I can't say this is the way *every* database treats `null`, but typically if you had a database with three records that contained, to use your example, "Running", "NotRunning", and null, then

```
... WHERE some_column = 'RUNNING'   <- returns one record
... WHERE some_column <> 'RUNNING'  <- returns one record
... WHERE some_column IS NULL       <- returns one record
```

If you're able to place a breakpoint on the LINQ statement and see if the generated SQL is visible anywhere in the object, you might be able to tell exactly what's going on. I'd guess you'll see `== null` being translated to `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

include null in your query

```
var thingsToRun = rep.Things.Where(t => t.Status == null || t.Status != "Running");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because null != Running is undefined : neither true nor false.

You might want to check out [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079109/linq-to-sql-query-not-returning-row-when-where-clause-compares-against-null-valu)